# The feedback link on non-existent sites is to MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed

Non-existent Stack Exchange sites have a link asking for feedback. That link is to Meta Stack Overflow. It should be to Meta Stack Exchange.

[image: Screenshot with annotations]

Comment: Do we even need an "all-sites" tag any more?

Comment: Probably not, @badp. Why not ask that as a separate [tag:burninate-request]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link will point to meta.stackexchange as of rev `2014.4.17.2174` here and `2014.4.17.1555` everywhere else.